# I downloaded a zip and extracted the files but I can't run it using npm start : reactj.s

Tags: reactjs

```
npm run start

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path C:\Users\xsaya\Downloads\dates-bazaar-master\package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\xsaya\Downloads\dates-bazaar-master\package.json'npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\xsaya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-26T08_29_51_127Z-debug.log
```

Comment: There is the location of a complete log file on the last line you posted. You should look at it, and if it does not help you to find the problem, you may edit your post with relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of:

1. First run

   ```
   npm init
   ```

   To create `package.json`
2. Delete `package-lock.json` if you have it

Answer (score 0):

See if there is a package.json file.

And did you do:
`npm install`